# Prompt a user for input from Git GUI

Tags: git, sh

I have a `pre-push` script that I want to run every time I push code to my remote repo. (Running OSX 10.11.6 and Git 2.6.4)

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "*** Did you run tests and lint? (y/n) " -n 1 -r < /dev/tty
echo # move to a new line
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        echo "*** WITH GREAT POWER COMES GREAT RESPONSIBILITY... ***"
        exit 0
fi

echo "*** ABORTING GIT PUSH ***"
exit 1
```

This script works perfectly if I'm running it from the command line, and it does technically "work" when I try to push using `git gui` -- the problem is that Git GUI just hangs as there is no input box for me to enter anything.

Can I even do this?

Answer (score 3):

Part of git-gui includes a separate script `git-gui--askpass` which is typically used to request passwords using a UI but can also do yes/no queries. The following replacement works with git-gui rather than reading the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

yno=$(git gui--askpass "Did you run the tests and lint (yes/no)?")
if [ "$yno" = "yes" ]
then
    echo "*** WITH GREAT POWER COMES GREAT RESPONSIBILITY... ***"
    exit 0
fi
echo "*** ABORTING GIT PUSH ***"
exit 1
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out. However, I'm also curious if that works well across other GUI tools (e.g. GitHub Desktop). I'm trying to write a "cross-tool" script for everyone on my team, but I'm guessing this simply isn't possible.

Comment: If you have a team then this is not really the way to do this. I'd just delete the irritating hook script on my machine. You should spend the time looking into integrating running your tests and lint on the server as part of a review process. ie: set up a continuous integration system with pull requests. Have devs push feature branches and raise pull requests. These can be automatically rejected for lint or test failures. GitLab is one such system. GitHub does it too (with hooks to various systems).